# Should every time new link to class be created while only one instance of this class is wanted?

Tags: java, oop

For example, there is a class Warrior which have linked class Sword. In class Sword defined field: public static int hp = 100; which shows the health points consumed by this type of weapon. There is need for a few classes Warrior. I think I need to define in class Warrior the link Sword (only once) to be able to get static field hp. How can I link it properly?

```
class public Warrior{
    public String name;
    public Sword s = new Sword(); // ???
}
class public Sword{
    public static int hp = 100;

}
```

Will `new Sword()` create link to class each time new Warrior created?
Can I define Sword class as static inside another Weapon class? (There is a need for multiple classes like Sword)

---

Is following structure correct? Can outer class be static and hold inside another static?

```
class public Warrior{
        public String name;

        public int SwordHp = Weapon.Sword().hp;
        public int BowHp = Weapon.Sword().hp;

    }

(abstract?) public static class Weapon{
    public static class Sword{
        public static int hp = 100;

    }
    public static class  Bow{
        public static int hp = 90;

    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should think about a `Weapon`superclass like `public class Sword extends Weapon`.

Comment: Can I define Sword class (child of Weapon class and nested) as a static (in order to get only one instance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting Static field hp you do not need to create

```
public Sword s = new Sword();
```

In warrior class. Static variables initialize on load. So you can access you hp anywhere without declaring in the specific classes by just using

Sword.hp ;

This do not have any impact on static variables.

```
 Sword s = new Sword()
```

As i understand you Have a warrior and different weapons as currently Sword.Every weapon has health points hp and Every Warior has its own weapon and health points. If you use static fields then these health points will be shared among all warriors if 50 wariors then all will using just 100 points togather which i expect you do not want so you should use:

```
class public Warrior{
    public String name;
    public Sword s = new Sword(); // ???
}
class public Sword{
    public  int hp = 100;

}
```

It will create a new sword with 100 health points every time a warrior is created  and every warior will consume his own health points. Hope it will help.

Comment: I have a warrior who have one type of weapon. Every weapon have hp (which is how much hp is takes after hit = damage). I don't need to track the hp of a weapon (how damaged it is). So I think I need only one static (or abstract??) class weapon which is parent of every child classes (Sword, Bow, etc).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you exactly want, but as your code example is now, the construction of a Warrior causes the construction of a Sword.

It depends on what you mean by "health points consumed by". If you want to keep track of all the damage this type of weapon has caused, you are good with your static HP field. If this is what you want, I would recommend using a system that keeps track of all sort of statistics. Something like this:

```
Statistics.getStatisticsForPlayer(playerName). // Get the statistics for a player
  increaseValue("damage_caused_by_sword", extraDamage); // increase that property
```

If you want to keep track of the health points per sword (which looks the most realistic to me, because a Sword isn't sharp forever), you should create the field non-static. This makes the field a property of every Sword instance.

Comment: One type of sword is wanted. So I think to make it static inside parent class.

Comment: But.... I think you don't completely understand what OOP is. A Class in Java is like "Human" (it is a kind, sort, race) and an Object of a Class, would be you. You (object) are a Human (class). So, saying that one type of sword is wanted is nonsense in this case. You create a class Sword, you defined a sword. As soon as you create an object of the Sword class, you will be able to "touch" it. Then you can give it to a specific warrior that can fight with it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, every time you will get a new Sword.

But, because hp is a static field, you will only get one of those.

Take a look at this link for more information:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 1):

If `hp` is `static`, you don't need a member `Sword` at all. You can access that field with `Sword.hp`.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of weapon types  is constant then enum would work well.

```
enum Weapon {
   Sword(100),
   Bow(90);

   private final int hp;
   private Weapon(int hp) {
      this.hp = hp;
   }

   int getHp();
}

public class Warrior {
   public String name;
   public Weapon weapon = Weapon.Sword;
}
```